# Delete step from Workflow in JIRA server edition v6.3.4

Tags: jira

[image: Screenshot of Workflow in Edit mode]

I'm trying to delete a step from a Workflow in JIRA.

I have read [on the interwebz](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/Cannot+Delete+Workflow+Step+from+Draft+Workflow) that to delete a Workflow step, you must make a copy of the Workflow and delete the step from the copy. Only I don't see any way to do that in the copy I have created.

I have tried this twice; it is a new workflow that is not assigned to any project and does not have a Workflow Scheme. It shows as "inactive". I have also tried deleting the transitions from the step, but that did not help.

Everything I've found about this topic assumes the Workflow is a "draft" but my copy does not appear to be a draft, so I don't know what the problem is. I've been digging around in the UI for an hour with no luck. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Best place I think to ask this is on the Atlassian site. They are most helpful. https://answers.atlassian.com/questions

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete transition in diagram view. delete the transition you want and complete the diagram flow.may be deleting transition may course the diagram flow.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the diagram view of your workflow. Click on the status that you want to remove and then you get a popup with a 'Remove status' link, like this:

[image]

Comment: The op doesn't mention the diagram view at all. He only mentions that he doesn't see any place where he can delete a step. This is possible in the diagram view, but only on "inactive" workflows, which is why you must copy the workflow first and work on the copy as described in the docs: https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloudkb/how-to-delete-a-status-in-jira-workflow-830283095.html  If you get a warning, then either your workflow is still active, or there's something else going on. What warning did you get?

Comment: Point restored (when SO lets me) as that is a very fair point, OP didn't say it was in that view. Thanks for adding your explanation, too.

Comment: This is a good answer but as @GlennV mentioned, it does not include the step to first copy the workflow so it's inactive.